# Does the Intuit REST API support reading bank transactions from QBO?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Does the Intuit REST API support reading bank transactions from QBO? I have checked the API explorer and documentation but cannot see anything that points to retrieving bank transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Bank Transactions is not supported as of now, but is planned for a future release but I do not have the dates for that.